# What is the difference between System Image and Conceptual model in interaction design?

Tags: user-interaction, human-computer-interface

I have Googled this but couldn't find a good answer. I understand that they are closed related. If someone has a definite answer on what the difference is I would be very grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Would love if you would select my answer, if it answers your question of course.

Answer (score 1):

System image is the authoritative combination of all available information. The system image is the collective, sum total of all information about a product such as manual, internet forums, physical appearance including signifiers and affordances. There is only one system image. A conceptual model on the other hand is the understanding about a product that is formed by the user. Every user has their own conceptual model which may or may not be accurate, and it may change with every interaction with the system image- that is a conceptual model may change, as one's understanding may change. Everyone's conceptual models are different, but every person has only one conceptual model of a product.